# DOJO DGRID Collection Sync With INPUTS

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid, dstore

I have a `dgrid` with inputs. My `dgrid` is in edit mode so users can add rows, edit rows and sort rows. When I look at my collection, it looks like

```
id: "1"

COLUMN1: "INPUT TYPE="text"...."

COLUMN2: "INPUT TYPE="text"...."
```

Note: I could not put the greater than and less than above with describing the inputs.

and so on. When I make a change on screen, for one of the inputs, the collection is not updated. So, when I enter a new row or sort the `dgrid`, all the entered data refreshes back to its original state. I know the reason is because the collection is not updated. Is it possible to update the collection or do I have to write my own code to do so? Please note, I am using a `dgrid` and NOT an onDemand grid.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please add some code on how you are initializing your `collection` and what all mixins are being used for it. As far as I can understand your problem, you need to add the `Trackable` mixin in your `collection`. Read its documentation [here](http://dstorejs.io/tutorials/realtime_stores.html).

From the documentation:

> We can add support for tracking the position of updates by using the Trackable mixin. With the Trackable mixin added to a store, we can call the store's track method to get a collection that includes index information in its delete, add, and update events.

This might be of your help.